# Pandas dataframe with MultiIndex: exclude level values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a multi-indexed pandas dataframe like the following one.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

arrays = [np.array(['bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux']),
          np.array(['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two']),
          np.array(['blo', 'bla', 'bla', 'blo', 'blo', 'blu', 'blo', 'bla'])]

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4), index=arrays)

df.sort_index(inplace=True)
```

which returns:

```
                    0         1         2         3
bar one bla  0.478461  1.030308  0.012688  0.137495
        blo  0.476041 -1.679848  1.346798  0.143225
    two bla  1.148882 -2.074197 -2.567959  1.258016
        blo  1.062280  3.846096 -0.346636  1.170822
foo one blo -0.761327  0.262105  0.151554  1.066616
    two blu  1.431951  0.043307 -0.326498  2.402536
qux one blo -0.622017 -0.566930  0.417977 -0.345238
    two bla  0.129273 -0.181396 -0.758381  0.995827
```

Now I want to select a subset by using a slice object:

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
subset = df.loc[idx[['bar'], :, :], :]
```

This returns:

```
                    0         1         2         3
bar one bla  0.478461  1.030308  0.012688  0.137495
        blo  0.476041 -1.679848  1.346798  0.143225
    two bla  1.148882 -2.074197 -2.567959  1.258016
        blo  1.062280  3.846096 -0.346636  1.170822
```

Now I want to exclude all rows having "blo" as level value. I know that I could select everything but the 'blo' values but my real dataframe is very big and I only know the level values which should not appear in the subset.

What's the easiest way to exclude certain level values from the subset?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IIUC, maybe you can mask your subset with:

```
subset = subset.iloc[subset.index.get_level_values(2) != 'blo']
```

Comment: subset = subset.iloc[~subset.index.get_level_values(2).str.contains('o')]

Comment: This checks if a substring is contained and inverses it by using the "~" operator. Maybe we should add this to my question and your answer!

Comment: Is there no analog of `df.xs`?

Answer (score 4):

You can do it this way:

```
In [263]:
subset.loc[subset.index.get_level_values(2) != 'blo']

Out[263]:
                    0         1         2         3
bar one bla -1.039335 -1.124656  0.057114 -0.284754
    two bla  0.007208 -0.403559 -1.317075 -0.340171
```

Answer (score 1):

For multiple values, I used this:

```
subset.iloc[~subset.index.get_level_values(2).isin(['blo'])]
```

In this way, you can use multiple values excluded at the same time.